# Python str() vs. '' - which is preferred

Tags: python

I have used some example code that uses str() instead of my normal habit of '' to denote an empty string.  Is there some advantage for using str()?  Eg:

```
 # .....
 d = dict()
 # .....
 # .....
 if v is None:
     d[c.name] = str()
 else:
     d[c.name] = v
```

It does seem to be slower.

```
$ python -m timeit "'.'.join(str(n)+'' for n in range(100))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 12.9 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit "'.'.join(str(n)+str() for n in range(100))"
100000 loops, best of 3: 17.2 usec per loop
```

Comment: If you have `from __future__ import unicode_literals` (bad idea), it does something different in Python 2. Otherwise, don’t use.

Comment: Side-note: Many of the same reasons for preferring `''` also call for using `{}` over `dict()`; `{}` has direct interpreter support, bypassing the comparatively expensive lookup and call machinery in favor of a single dedicated `BUILD_MAP` opcode (`dict()` takes about 4x longer than `{}` in local microbenchmarks).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Referring to the [Python manual](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) `str()` is used when:

1. You want the string representation of an object
2. You want to convert `bytes` (or other byte sequence, like `bytearray`) into a string

In all other cases, you should use `''`.

The fact that an empty `str()` call returns a blank string is a side effect and not the intended primary use of the method.

Answer (score 7):

The only advantage is that if `str` is redefined locally then `str()` will use that definition whereas `''` will not. Otherwise, they are equivalent (although not equal since the compiler will emit a function call in one case and a literal in the other).

Comment: Note: From a performance perspective, especially for immutable constants like `''`, the literal is *much* faster (~10x less time in local microbenchmarks). `''` is stored in the function constants, and loading it is essentially just looking it up in a C array and incrementing the reference count; using `str()` involves a built-in lookup (checking the globals `dict`, then the builtins `dict`), then a generic call bytecode (which ends up going through all the rigmarole of object construction only to realize it needs the empty string and returning it instead). Use `''`/`""`.